# Silverlight 3 Treeview

Tags: silverlight-3.0, treeview

Is there any way one can display the Silverlight 3 (Either toolkit version or the built-in Blend version) treeview horizontally?i.e. instead of top to bottom, I wan to go from left to right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no inherit method of the treeview to accomplish this. However, you might be able to achieve this by changing the ItemsPanelTemplate and the ItemsTemplate.

This [forum](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/56978/145672.aspx) discusses it in more detail.